# How to parse JSON in objective-C iOS

Tags: ios, objective-c, json, parsing, afnetworking

I want to parse JSON in Objective-C in iOS using AFNetworking library

```
{
  "success": 1,
  "row": [
    {
      "amount": 2800
    }
   ]
}
```

**CODE -**

```
 arrAmount = [responseObject valueForKey:@"row"];
 NSLog(@"%@",arrAmount);

 NSString *strAmount =[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@", [arrAmount valueForKey:@"amount"]];

 self.lblAmount.text =[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",strAmount];
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Response of `row`contain array not Dictionary, so access amount from first object of Array.

```
NSarray *arrAmount = [responseObject objectForKey:@"row"];
if arrAmount.count > 0 {
    NSDictionary *dic = [arrAmount objectAtIndex:0];
    NSString *strAmount = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d", [dic objectForKey:@"amount"]];
    self.lblAmount.text = strAmount;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

use NSDictionary:

```
NSDictionary *dict = [responseObject valueForKey:@"row"];
NSLog(@"value = %@",[dict valueForKey:@"amount"]);  // fetch amount value

array = [dict valueForKey:@"amount"];   // // fetch all amount value in array
NSLog(@"array = %@", array.description);
```

Comment: This will never work because key `row` contain Array not dictionary.

Comment: @NiravD nice to have your concern but this will work :))

Comment: can you explain how ?

Comment: i think the `( )` signs signals node is an array not `[ ]` and i checked after your message ..

Comment: Its up to use but i am sure it is array also op use `arrAmount` as var name that suggest it is array.

Comment: its upto parse the data also, user can get the data using `dict` or `array` both options are there i worked with many files having same `json` structure .....anyway nice to communicate with you :))

Answer (score 0):

Use `objectForKey` instead of `valueForKey`

```
NSDictionary *responseObject;
NSArray *arrAmount;
arrAmount = [responseObject objectForKey:@"row"];
NSLog(@"%@",arrAmount);
NSString *strAmount =[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@", [[arrAmount objectAtIndex:0] objectForKey:@"amount"]];
```