# How to represent Json data on iphone screen?

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, json

```
{
    Flows =     (
        flow456
    );

    flow456 =     (
        format789,
        format123
    );
    format123 =     {
        row1 =         {
            label = Price;
            textbox =             {
                height = 111;
                width = 333;
            };
        };
        row2 =         {
            button = yes;
        };
    };
    format123Rows =     (
        row1,
        row2
    );
    format789 =     {
        row1 =         {
            label = Price;
            textbox =             {
                height = 111;
                width = 333;
            };
        };
        row2 =         {
            button = yes;
        };
    };
    format789Rows =     (
        row1,
        row2
    );
}
```

Above is the json object which i want to display on iphone screen. Which is the best layout to display data on screen? I have tried UIView, UIStackView but not able to make it. How to display it in row wise?
As shown in image [Click here to see image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6lEg9.jpg)

Answer (score 0):

You need to convert your json object to String and display on UITextview. If you are reading JSON object from bundle, You can use below.

```
**NSString *filePath = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"Data" ofType:@"JSON"];

    //création d'un string avec le contenu du JSON
    NSString *myJSON = [[NSString alloc] initWithContentsOfFile:filePath encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding error:NULL];
    self.textview.text = myJSON;**
```

If you are getting the JSON object from webservice, you can try the below.

```
NSData *jsonData = [NSJSONSerialization dataWithJSONObject:JSONDic
                                                   options:NSJSONWritingPrettyPrinted 
                                                     error:&error];
NSString *jsonString = [[NSString alloc] initWithData:jsonData encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
```

Comment: If you need as in the screenshot, you need to parse the JSON. Please refer to : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39487854/how-to-parse-json-in-objective-c-ios

Comment: As i mentioned in image like that i want to represent  that json data. I need which layout is better to fit that json object inside that layout?

Comment: I believe you want to display some text in the labels.. you need to create the layout with labels/textfields (or however you want it to be) and you have parse and assign the text to the respective label.
Refer these:
1. https://www.raywenderlich.com/5492/working-with-json-in-ios-5
2. https://www.appcoda.com/parse-xml-and-json-web-service/

Comment: I want to display row wise dynamically created labels, textbox and button. But i am not getting which is the best layout to display this.